# Cannot Resolve symbol "OnItemSelectedListener"

Tags: xml, android-studio-import

```
package com.example.android.mycalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ***OnItemSelectedListener***{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Multiply");
        categories.add("Divide");
        categories.add("Subtract");
        categories.add("Add");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

> I am unable to import my OnItemSelectedListener Class on my main java file in android studio..I have selected the auto import settings..It is showing error for my above code saying;'cannot resolve 'OnItemSelectedListener'' when  i use the interface for my class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace your code with the below code it will work now

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        // Spinner Drop down elements
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Multiply");
        categories.add("Divide");
        categories.add("Subtract");
        categories.add("Add");
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please point out the mistake which the OP was making, to help him and anyone else who comes across this issue. To help them learn from their mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

Just paste this along with other package import:

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
```